# Read files in python

Tags: python

Python learner. So please excuse me.
I am following: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

I want to read a file; here is my file:

```
# cat test 
line1 word1
line2 word2
line3 word3
line4 word4
```

and here it my code:

```
>>> f = open ('test')
>>> for line in f:
...     print f
... 
<open file 'test', mode 'r' at 0xb7729180>
<open file 'test', mode 'r' at 0xb7729180>
<open file 'test', mode 'r' at 0xb7729180>
<open file 'test', mode 'r' at 0xb7729180>
```

How and why i am getting above output? I was hoping that it will print each line per line. 
What am I missing here. looking at the link mentioned above, my syntax seems to be OK but the output is not

Thanks.

Comment: why are you printing `f`, it is a `file handler`,, you need to print `line`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing the file handle, replace ***print f*** with ***print line***:

```
f = open ('test')
for line in f:
    print line
```

Answer (score 3):

During the iteration, you are printing `f` instead of the `line` variable.

```
>>> f = open ('test')
>>> for line in f: 
...        print line
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for line in open('test')
    print line
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the lines with a readline function. Then it turns each line into a list value. That is when you can do your for statement.

Comment: Nope; that's what 'for line in f:' does; it returns an iterator over the lines of the file. Only use readline() if you can't do things the simpler way :)

Answer (score 0):

`for line in f:`

This means 'iterate through the contents of f, assigning each item to the variable named 'line''. Not the converse. f won't change.. it's what you are getting the data from, not the variable you are assigning it to.

That said, the other answer I saw.. from someone whose name starts with 'D'.. is correct: you want to `print (line)`, not `print(f)`. I write that with ()'s because it's a good habit to get into, it makes your code compatible with both Python 2.x and Python 3.x.